# Subquery with aggregate function SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal is update the object_category column of the Inventory table for the objects with the least amount of items in the table (count(name))

I know that when using a subquery for the IN clause, the subquery must return a single column or value. However, I am not sure how to accomplish my goal while remaining syntactically correct.

This is the code that I have so far, the subquery by itself yields the correct two objects to be updated, just not when I put it in the IN clause

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET object_category = 'ABC'
WHERE Inventory.object_category in (
select count(name) as nameCount , object_category
from Inventory
group by object_category
having nameCount <= min(nameCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to express this logic with a `join`.  If you only want to update one category, then this will suffice

```
UPDATE Inventory i JOIN
       (SELECT count(name) as nameCount, object_category
        FROM Inventory
        GROUP BY object_category
        ORDER BY nameCount
        LIMIT 1
       ) ii
       ON ii.object_category = i.object_category
    SET i.object_category = 'ABC';
```

Your subquery doesn't make sense and will not work.